# find and insert row to another table using mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have the following three tables in mysql database named **`My_Company`**

```
mysql> desc employee;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| Emp_Name | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Division | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc tools;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Division  | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| Tool_No   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| Tool_Name | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> desc employee_tools;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Id    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Tool  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)

--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to insert the rows from table tools to table employee_tools when insert a new row on table employee.

Example, if i insert a new row to employees values as `('1', 'Michel', 'Network')`
then the the trigger should to find the `tool_No` & `tool_names` of division from table tools
and add the rows to `employee_tools`

```
mysql> insert into employee values('1','Michel','Network');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> select * from employee;
+----+----------+----------+
| Id | Emp_Name | Division |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | Michel   | Network  |
+----+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tools;
+----------+---------+--------------+
| Division | Tool_No | Tool_Name    |
+----------+---------+--------------+
| Network  |       1 | Crimper      |
| Network  |       2 | LAN Tester   |
| Network  |       3 | Sleaver      |
| Hardware |       1 | Screw drv    |
| Hardware |       2 | Power Tester |
| Hardware |       3 | Plyer        |
+----------+---------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from employee_tools;
+------+--------------+
| Id   | Tool         |
+------+--------------+
|    1 | 1_Crimper    |
|    1 | 2_LAN Tester |
|    1 | 3_Sleaver    |
+------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `employee_INSERT` $$
CREATE TRIGGER `employee_INSERT` 
AFTER INSERT ON `employee`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO employee_tools (Id, Tool)
    SELECT new.Id, tools.Tool_Name 
            FROM tools
            WHERE tools.Division = new.Division;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: is it possible to insert into employee_tools (Id,Tool) values ('new.id', 'Tools.Tool_No & Tools.Tool_Name') ?

Comment: @dinesh.mic Yes, that would be possible, but it would violate the principle of *Normalization*. If you store `tools.Tool_No` in `employee_tools` then you shouldn't also store `tools.Tool_Name` in `employee_tools` because you already have that information available from the `tools` table.

Comment: how to write a trigger like this for fire when update on employee.division

Comment: @dinesh.mic The current trigger fires `AFTER INSERT ON employee`. You'll need to create a second trigger that fires `AFTER UPDATE ON employee`. For more details, look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//create-trigger.html).